# Why is drop box always trying and failing to connect to me on a high port in iptables logs?

Tags: log, iptables

Continually getting message in logs:

```
IPTables Packet Dropped: IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=c4:17:fe:65:51:f8:20:76:00:aa:98:78:08:00 
SRC=199.47.216.148 DST=192.168.1.102 LEN=218 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=52253 DF  #
PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=60684 WINDOW=31 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
```

I did a `whois` and know that the source IP `199.47.216.148` has something to do with Dropbox, which I do have installed, but why is it continually trying to connect to me on my 60684 port and clogging up the logs? Dropbox is otherwise working completely fine. It has established connections like

```
dropbox   2409          myuser   17u  IPv4 220578      0t0  TCP     127.0.0.1:37255->127.0.0.1:8080 (CLOSE_WAIT)
dropbox   2409          myuser   23u  IPv4 221364      0t0  TCP     127.0.0.1:37273->127.0.0.1:80y80 (CLOSE_WAIT)
dropbox   2409          muser   26u  IPv4 221496      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:37279->127.0.0.1:8080 (ESTABLISHED)
dropbox   2409          myuser   27u  IPv4 216008      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:37261->127.0.0.1:8080 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

(I should perhaps mention that I have `privoxy` and `dansguardian` installed too, so only `privoxy` is allowed `http, https` outbound to `port 80`, and only `dansguardian` is allowed local outbound to `privoxy` which listens on `8118`, and `firefox` is then forced to connect to `dansguardian` on `127.0.0.1:8080`. This means Dropbox connects through a "proxy" of `127.0.0.1:8080` too, just like firefox does. Not sure this has any relevance but just incase. Pretty much all other standard outbound is allowed. )

My `iptables` rules for reference are set to drop and log all inbound connections unless tracked by

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

As I say the strange thing is that Dropbox appears to otherwise work fine, so whatever it wants with this inbound connection must be pretty minor, but it is annoying to continually see it in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing this is because only root can open ports below 1024 so any application that wants an outgoing connection will open a port higher than that.

You can open ports between 1025 and 65335 inclusively as a non-root user.